# Vue functional calendar updating calendar configs dynamically is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, calendar

I have used `vue-functional-calendar` [Vue Functional Calendar](https://github.com/ManukMinasyan/vue-functional-calendar) in my VueJS app in the following way.

```
<FunctionalCalendar
      v-model="calendarData"
      v-on:dayClicked="date_selected"
      v-on:changedMonth="fetch_disabled_dates_by_month"
      :is-date-range="true"
      :is-date-picker="true"
      :configs="calendarConfigs">
 </FunctionalCalendar>
```

And the `calendarData` and `configs` are as follows:

```
export default {
    name: "ReservationForm",
    components: {
        FunctionalCalendar,
    },
    data() {
        return {
             calendarData: {},
                 calendarConfigs: {
                      sundayStart: false,
                      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                      isDatePicker: true,
                      isDateRange: true,
                      disabledDates: [] //it will be updated dynamically from API response
                 },
                 current_month: 1 //dynamic
            };
        },
 .......................
```

Now I'm trying to update the value of `disabledDates` based on back end API request response.
`this.calendarConfigs.disabledDates = response.data.disabledDates;` here response is coming from server. Though the `response.data.disbledDates` properly formatted array but here but the value is not updating on the calendar!

For example in the mounted method I tried to fetch disabled dates through API, though API is returning correct data but it's not updating on the calendar.

```
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        axios.post("/api/get-disabled-dates", {
            month: this.current_month,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.data.result == 'success'){
                this.calendarConfigs.disabledDates = response.data.disabledDates;
//the above line should update the disabled dates at calendar but it's not. Even if I hard code the value here it's not working
            }
        });
```

Comment: What you posted is not enough to repro. Could you please create a *runnable* [mcve], showcasing the exact error you're seeing? If you need a node-based online sandbox, give codesanbox.io a go, but any alternative will do, as long as your example is minimal and the bug is reproducible.

Comment: Hi @tao thanks for your comment. I have updated the question now. Would you please check? Actually there is no error it generates. Just thing is not happening as desired. Thanks